# Transitions dont show properly on page load

Tags: html, css, angular

I've got a gauge meter that needs to be filled according to a variable sent to the html file. 
To do that, I've set the initial value to zero, like this:

```
  transform:rotate(.0turn);
  transition: all 1.3s ease-in-out;
```

Whenever the html is loaded (for the first time, or with f5), it makes a weird animation that I'd like to avoid, even though that when I change the section I'm in using (from the side-nav) and change back, the animation is smooth and shows as it has to.

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'transform': 'rotate(' + dashService.valor_radio + 'turn)' }">
```

This is the part where I send the value from the html page to the CSS file.
Every question I google seems to be the opposite, how to avoid transitions on page load.
As a note: I cant use JQuery

Comment: Angular has a whole animation section to it, try to use it. There are many cavities, you will miss if you do it by yourself.

Comment: By doing by yourself you mean without using the animation section? I tought transitions and animations where different things. thank you

Comment: Indeed, animations and transitions thought not trivial, might be used for any animation that occurs on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely seeing an initial stutter in the animations because there's a lot of action going on during the initial load, especially if it's in a lazily loaded module.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you may be able to solve this with a short delay in the animation:

```
transition: all 1.3s 100ms ease-in-out;
                      ^ delay
```

Ahh, ok, based on your comment it sounds like it's also animating the width and/or height on the container as the DOM is built. Try changing `transition: all` to a more specific attribute like `transition: transform`

Comment: I tried this but the delay doesnt seem to help. It should be a circle rotating, and instead of rotating over its correct centerpoint, it rotates seemingy out of axis.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:
Apparently, having 'all' after transition made all my parameters transition, instead of 'transform:rotate' only.
It was as easy as replacing 'transition: all', to 'transition: transform'